the problem with entering information into the sqlite3 database in C++
here is my code
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void CreateTable(int open, sqlite3* db, char* ERR)
{
    cout << "Создание таблицы: ";
    const char* SQLTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Age INTEGER);";
    open = sqlite3_exec(db, SQLTable, 0, 0, &ERR);
    if (open)
    {
        cerr << RED << "ПРОВАЛ" << ERR << endl << RESET;
        sqlite3_free(ERR);
    }
    else
        cout << GREEN << "УСПЕХ" << RESET << endl;
}
void SetDB(sqlite3* db, const wstring& name, int age, sqlite3_stmt** stmt)
{
    const char* insertSQL = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Age) VALUES (?, ?)";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertSQL, -1, stmt, nullptr) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Используем sqlite3_bind_text16 для вставки wstring
        sqlite3_bind_text16(*stmt, 1, name.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
        sqlite3_bind_int(*stmt, 2, age);
        if (sqlite3_step(*stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
            cerr << "Вставка данных: " << RED << "ПРОВАЛ" << endl << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << RESET;
        else
            cout << "Вставка данных: " << GREEN << "УСПЕХ" << endl << RESET;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Подготовка запроса: " << RED << "ПРОВАЛ" << RESET << endl;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(*stmt);
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(65001);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    wstring name;
    int age;
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt = nullptr;
    sqlite3* db;
    char* ErrorMsg = 0;
    int open_db = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    ERRORsql(open_db, db);
    CreateTable(open_db, db, ErrorMsg);
    cout << "Начните ввод для информации в бд" << endl <<
        "Для завершения работы пропишите //exit" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Имя: " << endl << ">> ";
        getline(wcin, name);
        if (name == L"//exit")
            break;
        cout << "Возраст (по желанию или же -)" << endl << ">> ";
        cin >> age;
        SetDB(db, name, age, &stmt);
    }
    cout << "До скорых встреч" << endl;
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

For some reason, when I try to enter a name into the database using the Russian language, the Name column is just empty—literally a void—although information is entered in other columns. As I understand it, this is a problem with encoding. However, after trying everything I could at the moment, I did not succeed. Please do not criticize too much, since I just started learning C++, and thank you in advance! ^^
I changed the encoding in the Windows console itself and tried using wstring; I set various encodings via SetConsoleCP, but nothing helped me.

I think I've solved my question if someone also has such a problem, then here's what I did first, I thought that if I didn't run the .cpp file itself, but run the compiled one.exe so the whole Russian language in this case begins to be written in utf-8 encoding and is correctly entered into the database. also, for correct output to the console, I added the following code to the main function
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(65001); 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);

if you follow my method, everything will work, although I understand that most likely there are ways for the IDE to work correctly if there are other solutions, I will be happy to listen to them and thank you to everyone who tried to help

You could try setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru.UTF-8"); as well…
